# Why Sling Configuration has two different formats

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix, sling

in Sling, configuration can be deployed either via a **sling:osgiConfig** node and via a **nt:file** node having the configuration values.
When i make some changes in Felix Console in some configuration deployed via sling:osgiConfig node, it gets converted to nt:file format.

Why there are these two different formats for configurations in Sling. is there any significant difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is mostly for historical reasons, in some cases it's more convenient to provide configurations as hierarchical resources (sling:OsgiConfig) and if the config is coming from a filesystem for example, files are more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

@Shashi sling:osgiConfig changing to nt:file when you make changes in felix console is expected behaviour. This will not cause any issue when you try to read the config value from java class. You will just not be able to edit the run mode config via crxde when it has changed to nt:file as it stores data as binary content.

However there is a way to disable this behaviour, you will have to uncheck "Enable Write Back" at /system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr.impl.JcrInstaller as mentioned in this [thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1214363).

OSGi config [best practices](https://blog.kristianwright.com/2013/08/21/aem-best-practice-osgi-configurations/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm also interested in knowing is there any specific reason(technical or historical may be) to have two different representations of the same configurations in sling.